# Javascript removeEventListener on dynamic components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so my code looks like

```
useEffect(() => {
    const element = document.getElementById('player');
    document.getElementById('fullscreen').addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (screenfull.isEnabled) {
            screenfull.request(element);
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('fullscreen-out').addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (screenfull.isEnabled) {
            screenfull.toggle(element);
        }
    });
    return () => {
        document.getElementById('fullscreen').removeEventListener('click', () => {
            if (screenfull.isEnabled) {
                screenfull.request(element);
            }
        });
        document.getElementById('fullscreen-out').removeEventListener('click', () => {
            if (screenfull.isEnabled) {
                screenfull.toggle(element);
            }
        });
    }
}, [])
```

The content platform I'm building has a master state that the admins can change at any time, some components, (such as in the example code) will not be displayed&rendered on the certain state.

Now the problem then lies in the detachment of a event listener. When the state changes, the component is then ripped out of the DOM and the event listener then cannot be removed(in my understanding).

So this causes the following error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeEventListener')`

How can I detach the listener when the component exits?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem. If you delegate from the nearest static container, then you can decide aat event time to honour the event or ignore it.

Comment: I thought that when you use reactjs (not rxjs btw) you need to stop using the DOM completely and let React handle that for you - by using `addEventListener` directly you're bypassing the _chain of command_ which will put reactjs's DOM management into an invalid state.

Comment: Also, you cannot use `removeEventListener` with a closure nor any kind of anonymous-function. You need to use the exact same function-reference in both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dai pointed out in his comment, I should've let React do the work and use the event handlers the framework provides.

onClick is an event  handler by itself, and does the exact same thing as the code I provided in my first example.

Thanks Dai.

```
function requestScreenfull() {
    const element = document.getElementById('player');
    if (screenfull.isEnabled) {
        screenfull.request(element);
    }
}

function toggleScreenfull() {
    const element = document.getElementById('player');
    if (screenfull.isEnabled) {
        screenfull.toggle(element);
    }
}


 <button onClick={requestScreenfull}>Fullscreen</button>
 <button onClick={toggleScreenfull}>Toggle</button>
```

More information on [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)